# Copy the console line into clipboard with a hotkey

Tags: shell, ubuntu, console

Without using xclip or xsel or others and preferably with a hotkey, i need to copy the line from inside Ubuntu console into the main clipboard.

Is there a way to do that?
I tried CTRL + U and CTRL+ SHIFT + V, but that puts it into the console clipboard, not main clipboard.

I need to know if there is a hotkey which copies the current line from console to the clipboard.

Or if i can read the console clipboard from a file and get the values into the OS clipboard.

Comment: Try Ctrl + Shift + C, if it doesn't work you should be able to set your hotkeys in the preferences.

Comment: @Scott, it works but i need to highlight the whole command with my mouse. Is there a way to select whole command with hotkeys? And then use Ctrl + Shift + C